# Transform non-convex optimization problem to convex one by add variable

Tags: convex-analysis, matlab, transformation, non-convex-optimization

my non-convex optimization problem is as follow:
\begin{align}
\min_x a_1 x_1^2 + a_2x_1 + a_3 - \frac{a_4}{x_1}
\end{align}
subject to:
\begin{align}
\frac{c_1}{x_1}+c_2\leq d_{\mathrm{max}} 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
x_{\mathrm{min}} \leq{x_1} \leq x_{\mathrm{max}} 
\end{align}
where $x_{\mathrm{min}}> 0$. My question is: Can I add a new variable $x_2$ and related with it the constraint in order to transform my optimization problem to convex one?
\begin{align}
\min_x x_2 - \frac{a_4}{x_1}
\end{align}
subject to:
\begin{align}
\frac{c_1}{x_1}+c_2\leq d_{\mathrm{max}} 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
x_{\mathrm{min}} \leq{x_1} \leq x_{\mathrm{max}} 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
a_1 x_1^2 + a_2x_1 + a_3  \leq x_2 
\end{align}
Theoretically, based on Boyd book "Convex optimization" the problem is convex when the objective function is convex or concave and all constraints are convex but I put the transformed problem to MATLAB fmincon solver which applies SQP algorithm and sometimes I get no optimal solution (lower bound of $x_1$. When I change the algorithm to interior-point method everything is correct. Thus, I am thinking that the problem is in the transformation or in the applied algorithm.

Comment: The transformation is completely fine, but it does not change the convexity status of the problem. That depends only on the signs of $a_1$ and $a_4$.

Comment: A note on the solvers: SQP and IPM are designed to converge towards stationary points (local minima). The solution you get with SQP, while not globally optimal, is probably locally optimal. It's just that both methods take different paths in the search space and may find different solutions.

Comment: Thank for answers, according to the first comment: $a_1$ and $a_4$ are positive. To be honest I thought that if the problem is convex it means that local optimum is a global as well and thus each algorithm should achieve an optimal solution.

Comment: @user3648211 If $a_4>0$ your problem is not convex.

Comment: Original of course but what with transformed? Theoretically, there is the affine function minus convex for $x_1>0$, thus the objective function is concave while all constraints are convex and the optimization problem is convex as well.

Comment: @user3648211 The objective function is concave but you are MINIMIZING. If you were maximizing then a problem with concave objective would classify as a convex optimization problem. (Of course then quadratic constraint would be the wrong way around but that's an unrelated story).

Comment: @Michal Adamaszek in my opinion your classification is less important in my question because I can add minus in the objective function and I will have convex function. Thus, please answer on my question in this topic: Does the transformation is correct and does it make the problem convex?

Comment: @user3648211 Yes, the transformation is correct. No, it does not make the problem convex.